# Populate second Dropdown using JSON PHP SQL Server

Tags: php, json, sql-server

I am brand new to any type of web development and Im trying to populate a dropdown using the value from a previous dropdown as my parameter but my second dropdown refuses to populate. I'm not seeing any errors from my Xampp (error checking is turned on) so I'm really not sure what's going on.
Here is my code.

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once 'config.php';


if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    // user is not logged in, do something like redirect to login.php
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}

$page_title = "SSI-Portal";
$page_description = "Description of this page";

$userid = $_SESSION['user'];
$q= $conn->query("SELECT permissions FROM logins WHERE name='$userid'");
$perm = $q->fetchColumn();

$q= $conn->query("SELECT dept_id FROM logins WHERE name='$userid'");
$dept = $q->fetchColumn();

$_SESSION['perm'] = $perm;

include 'header.php';

    $rows = array();
    if(isset($_POST['jobtype'])) {
  $tsql = "SELECT [job number] FROM job_view WHERE completed = 0 and jobtype=?";
    $getResults = $conn->prepare( $tsql);
    $getResults->execute(array($_GET['jobtype']));
    $rows = $getResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Time</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css?version=62">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?version=52">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css?version=51">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
                                <script src="js/main.js"></script>
                                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm">
                                    Add New Time
                                </button>

                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
                                        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <!-- Modal Header -->
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" 
                                                        data-dismiss="modal">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                                </button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                                    New Time
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Modal Body -->
                                            <div class="modal-body">

                                                <form role="form">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>Job Type :</label>
                                                        <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="75px" name="job" id="jobType">
                                                            <option>SVC</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="75px">
                                                            <select name="numbers" id="jobumbers">
                                                            </select>
                                                            <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                                                            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
                                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                                                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
                                                                });
                                                                function populateJobNumbers() {

                                                                $.getJSON('./time.php', {jobType:$('#jobType').val()}, function(data) {

                                                                var select = $('#jobNumbers');
                                                                var options = select.prop('options');
                                                                $('option', select).remove();

                                                                $.each(data, function(index, array) {
                                                                options[options.length] = new Option(array['numbers']);
                                                                });

                                                                });

                                                                }

                                                                $(document).ready(function() {

                                                                populateJobNumbers();
                                                                $('#jobtype').change(function() {
                                                                populateJobNumbers();
                                                                });

                                                                });
                                                            </script>
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                                        </form>

                                                        <!-- Modal Footer -->
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                                                    data-dismiss="modal">
                                                                Close
                                                            </button>
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                                Save changes
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </body>
                                            </html>
```

Like I said the is my first go at this so please go easy on me. Thanks!

Comment: Firs of all, you have a tag SELECT missing close tag.
Find this...
select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="75px"  
you have to close that with /select (cant write real html here)

Comment: I think maybe you mistyped since that SELECT is the same like the one before

Comment: Yea, that shouldnt be there....Im trying to add "Option" in populateJobNumbers function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a tag `<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="75px">` missing close tag `</select>`. Maybe you mistyped that.

Second, you try to reuse the same php page to get ajax data and show HTML, depending on $GET, this is not a good practice, but we can keep this for the future.

I think that `echo json_encode($rows);` must be followed by the line `exit;` (which replace the deprecated word `die()` . So your code would like...

```
if(isset($_POST['jobtype'])) {
    $tsql = "SELECT [job number] FROM job_view WHERE completed = 0 and jobtype=?";
    $getResults = $conn->prepare( $tsql);
    $getResults->execute(array($_GET['jobtype']));
    $rows = $getResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($rows); //this line WITHIN the IF block
    exit; //this line WITHIN the IF block
}
```

Last tip: try to indent properly your code to easy read it!! :))

ie: those `<link rel="stylesheet">` and `<script>` in the header must be at the same indent level